# W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed for Android app broadcaster (target sdk 27)

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to add a [broadcaster](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#kotlin) to [this](https://github.com/micer/clipboard-service) Android clipboard service. I have not programmed Kotlin before.

The `receiver` portion of `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">             
 <intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="eu.micer" />
 </intent-filter>
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="eu.micer.BOO" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The project file `MyBroadcastReceiver.kt` (Kotlin) that overrides `onReceive` for the receiver reads simply:

```
package eu.micer.clipboardservice

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver

import android.widget.Toast
import android.util.Log

private const val TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver"

class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Hi there!")
    }
}
```

I can build, and install the app fine, and can initiate its bare-bones activity:

```
$adb shell am start -n eu.micer.clipboardservice/eu.micer.clipboardservice.EmptyActivity
---
Starting: Intent { cmp=eu.micer.clipboardservice/.EmptyActivity }
```

The broadcast fails though: after I run

```
$ adb shell am broadcast -a eu.micer.BOO
```

I get

```
$ adb logcat BroadcastQueue:W *:S
---
...
...
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=eu.micer.BOO flg=0x400010 } to eu.micer.clipboardservice/.MyBroadcastReceiver
```

---

I know there was much ado about [implicit broadcasters](https://www.journaldev.com/23653/android-oreo-implicit-and-explicit-broadcast-receiver#implicit-vs-explicit-broadcastreceivers) no longer being declarable in `AndroidManifest.xml` for sufficiently recent SDKs, but does that apply above? Given the way it's declared, does that broadcaster count as implicit or explicit?

Comment: Unless your broadcast intent contains target package/component it's considered implicit. For explicit broadcast you can add `-n eu.micer.clipboardservice/.MyBroadcastReceiver` to your command.

Comment: Thank you! This worked and resulted in the message ('Hi there') appearing in the log. I'll be happy to accept this as an answer, if you post it as such.